# Light sequencing format for theater + interior lighting

Tags: computer-science, rgb

What language powers DMX light shows? Is there a web-technology friendly way to control DMX lights - to specify color sequences for disco rooms, home lighting?

I'm imagining something like this:
00:01 #FFFFFF -- white lights at the beginning
00:05 #0000FF -- go to blue
00:25 #ee00ee -- fade to different color

Thanks.

Comment: WHAT ARE YOU TALKING ABOUT??

Comment: I don't want to make my own language, but am looking for the language that powers DMX light shows.

Answer (score 0):

The software depends of hardware, an example of software may be: http://www.chauvetlighting.com/showXpress-software/

http://www.dts-lighting.com/DMX_MASTER_SOFTWARE?print=1

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMX512

Comment: Right, but the software somehow encodes the sequences of light to give down to the hardware, that format it what I'm interested in. Afaik there isn't a standard?

Comment: I dont thinks so...but i still googling around ;)